# Creating an empty array of Strings of size x that can be updated

Tags: ocaml, ml

I'm trying to create an array of strings so that I can modify the contents of the strings depending on the input parameter of a function. I've only started to use OCaml recently so I may be missing something simple here. Currently I have:

```
  let myArray = Array.make x "" in
    for i = 0 to Array.length myArray do
    myArray[i] = "SOME STRING HERE";
  done;
```

However when doing this, I get the following error when performing `ocamlbuild`

> Error: This expression has type string array
>          This is not a function; it cannot be applied.

Comment: Please don't keep changing your code. It makes the previous answers incorrect.

Comment: Please test your code to make sure it actually demonstrates the problem and does not contain an error on every other token. See how to make a [mcve] for more.

Comment: You have edited your code so that it now works OK, but this makes your question incoherent. Please leave your original question intact for later readers of StackOverflow.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I have rollbacked to revision 1. You could have done the same BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment to an array looks like this in OCaml:

```
myArray.(i) <- "SOME STRING HERE"
```

As an additional comment, your loop is accessing past the end of the array. The last element of an array is `Array.length array - 1`.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake with that. However that did not fix the problem as per my edit

Comment: You are still using `[]` for indexing. Indexing of arrays uses `.()`.

Comment: Sorry forgot to change that in the question. Error still applies

Comment: Syntax wise yes, but it's still giving the error This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type int

Comment: If I copy/paste your code, it works for me. I tried it twice. Furthermore I see no problems with it :-)

Comment: Is there a problem when trying to update the values of an array from within a function then :S

Comment: Your original question has been answered. If you're still having problems you should put together a new question. No, there is no problem updating arrays. They are mutable.

Comment: Apologies, I found where the problem lies now. It wasn't to do with the array, something else is causing it